# Iceface 2.0 commandLink partial submit doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have a page which takes in request params for place, then generate information,
for example, `http://example.com/xxx/weather.jsf?place=california`.
The purpose of doing this is to let user bookmark the link.

In the weather.jsf, there are two outputtext and a commandlink:

```
Humidity : <ice:outputText value="#{weatherBean.humidity}"/>
Visibility : <ice:outputText value="#{weatherBean.visibility}"/>
<ice:commandLink id="likeButton" 
  value="Like"
  actionListener="#{weatherBean.doLike}" />
```

In the managedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="weatherBean")
@RequestScoped
public class WeatherBean
{
 String humidity;
 String visibility;
 int numLike; 

 @PostConstruct
     public void init()
 {
  System.out.println("init called");
  HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
  String place = request.getParameter("place");
  setHumidity(WeatherDao.getHumidity(place));
  setVisibility(WeatherDao.getVisibility(place));
  setNumLike(GeneralDao.getNumLike());
 }

 public void doLike(ActionEvent event)
 {
  System.out.println("doLike called");
  GeneralDao.addNumberLike();
 }
}
```

Alright, the page generated perfectly.
However, when I click the `doLike` commandLink,
it always triggers the `init` method first, then call `doLike` method.
Since the request param is empty, all the other values reset.
Is there any way to prevent a refresh of the page or calling of `init` method?
I tried partialsubmit or immediate, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bean is @RequestScoped, so after executing the JSF lifecycle, your bean instance is lost, until the next request comes in, at which point you get a new instance of your bean, and the PostContruct re-executes.

Try changing the scope of your bean to something longer lived, like @ViewScoped.